# Python format() function

Tags: python, format

```
class name:
    def create(self):
        person=input("Enter your name")
        print('hello {}'.format(person))
```

During running the following error occurs!What is the mistake?

```
 o=name()
 o.create()
 Enter your nameshubham

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#53>", line 1, in <module>
o.create()
File "<pyshell#51>", line 3, in create
person=input("Enter your name")
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'shubham' is not defined
```

Comment: Are you using python 2? If you just started learning python I'd suggest you to move to python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your are using a lower version than Python 3.x so
you have to use `raw_input()` here since `input()` tries to interpret your feed.

You can find the explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x).